# Webview cant read </br> from predefined html file

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a html file that contain a lot of text and basic html tags. The file is inside **res/raw** folder.
However, when i tried to show this html from my webview, `</br`> is not working, while `<b></b>` is fine.**My min SDK is 8 and target SDK is 15.**

This is the screen shoot :

[image: webview screenshoot]

This is the html file :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<article align="center">

Printf(“Hello World ^_^”);</br></br>

<b>This section will explain about the objective of this apps.</b></br>
This apps is designed for those who want to learn Computer Science (programming), with no experience necessary (so you don’t have to worry about your age, background, education, etc. EVERYONE can learn programming!).</br> 
This apps will teach you about the basics of the programming using C languange.</br>
</article>
```

This is webview code :

```
webChapter.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/hello_world.html");
```

I tried this one, but no luck, the file even cant be read :

```
webChapter.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/raw/", "hello_world.html", "text/html", "UT-8", "");
```

Thanks :D

Comment: Do you mean `<br />`?

Comment: `</br>` is a closing tag... For an empty tag, the slash needs to be at the end (just as jprofitt suggested): `<br/>`

Comment: `br` is an empty tag and therefore does not need a closing tag [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp). `</br>` in invalid HTML

Comment: OMG..sorry for my poor knowledge of the html. Thank you very much :D
You can answer my question :D

Comment: @Eonasdan the one that make me confuse is its working in the web browser (i use GC). Thanks :D

Comment: @Eonasdan that is only true in HTML if you want to use xHTML then it needs to be closed. To be safe it is always best to close the tag regardless of content or not, as jprofitt said at the start, the closing / comes after the tag <br />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<br>` instead of `</br>`

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element

Comment: again, sorry for my poor html :D
Thanks :D

Comment: <br> is still showing this issue for me. Would <br /> not fix this??